# Python checkbox

Tags: python, tkinter

Только начал изучать python. Как можно реализовать события чекбоксов(checked, checkstate и т.д.)по аналогии с c#?

Псевдокод:

если чекбокс включили,то выполнить py_send('yes')

если чекбокс выключили, то py_send('no')

и при запуске формы чекбокс выключен, но никаких событий не выполняется (т.е. py_send('no') не отправляется автоматически).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переменная:

```
self.cbVar = IntVar()
```

Чекбокс:

```
self.cb = Checkbutton(self, text = "yes no", variable = self.cbVar, command = self.switch_button)
```

После:

```
def switch_button(self)
   sb = self.cbVar.get()
   if sb == 1:
     py_send('yes')
   else:
     py_send('no')
```

Писал с телефона, поэтому проверьте табуляцию.

Comment: Спасибо,работает!!